# Aegir: Could not generate database backup from mysqldump, after Calling hook drush_db_pre_provision_backup

Tags: linux, drupal-7, backup, aegir

I installed Aegir package manually on a Debian server Jessie with (Aegir3, Drush 7.1.0 , provision 7.x-3.4, hostmaster 7.x-3.4) and every thing goes nice, except the backup feature, here is what i done:

I activated the Hosting Site Backup Manager module to automate backups of my websites.

*********i couldn't install aegir in /var/aegir (cause i don't have privileges on other directories on that server), but it installed /production/my_aegir_user that has all aegir privileges user*********

After installation of a new site with Aegir, and when the backup tasks runs, it fails with the following log:

```
Task starts processing: Backup: www.mydomain.com    
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_task_validate  
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_alias_pre_hosting_task   
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_alias_pre_hosting_task 
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_clone_pre_hosting_task   
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_clone_pre_hosting_task 
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_migrate_pre_hosting_task 
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_migrate_pre_hosting_task   
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_package_pre_hosting_task 
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_package_pre_hosting_task   
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_remote_import_pre_hosting_task   
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_remote_import_pre_hosting_task 
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_site_pre_hosting_task    
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_site_pre_hosting_task  
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_site_backup_manager_pre_hosting_task 
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_site_backup_manager_pre_hosting_task   
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_sync_pre_hosting_task    
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_sync_pre_hosting_task  
-
Calling hook drush_hosting_task 
1 s.
Loaded alias @www.mydomain.com from file /production/my_aegir_user/.drush/www.mydomain.com.alias.drushrc.php    
-
Backend invoke: php /production/my_aegir_user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --backend=2 @www.mydomain.com provision-backup 2>&1    
-
php /production/my_aegir_user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --backend=2 @www.mydomain.com provision-backup 2>&1    
-
Bootstrap to phase 0.   
-
Bootstrap to phase 1.   
-
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() 
-
Loading drushrc "/production/my_aegir_user/platforms/template-uni-to/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php" into "drupal" scope.  
-
Initialized Drupal 7.43 root directory at /production/my_aegir_user/platforms/template-uni-to   
-
Find command files for phase 1 (max=1)  
-
Cache HIT cid: 7.1.0-commandfiles-1-a127e16d6e2aa0bf2587b0cbe8d820d4    
-
Found command: provision-backup (commandfile=provision) 
-
Loaded alias @server_localhost from file /production/my_aegir_user/.drush/server_localhost.alias.drushrc.php    
-
Loaded alias @server_master from file /production/my_aegir_user/.drush/server_master.alias.drushrc.php  
-
Driver type not specified for the db service, provide it with --db_service_type 
-
Loading apache driver for the http service  
-
Driver type not specified for the remote_import service, provide it with --remote_import_service_type   
-
Loading mysql driver for the db service 
-
Driver type not specified for the http service, provide it with --http_service_type 
-
Driver type not specified for the remote_import service, provide it with --remote_import_service_type   
-
Loaded alias @platform_templateUniTo from file /production/my_aegir_user/.drush/platform_templateUniTo.alias.drushrc.php    
-
Including /production/my_aegir_user/.drush/provision/db/backup.provision.inc    
-
Including /production/my_aegir_user/.drush/provision/platform/backup.provision.inc  
-
Calling hook drush_provision_drupal_provision_backup_validate   
-
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() 
-
Loading drushrc "/production/my_aegir_user/platforms/template-uni-to/sites/www.mydomain.com/drushrc.php" into "site" scope. 
-
Initialized Drupal site www.mydomain.com at sites/www.mydomain.com  
-
Find command files for phase 2 (max=)   
-
Cache HIT cid: 7.1.0-install_profile-c07b6dfdb3c6ead14c4903f1c5a39aca   
-
Cache HIT cid: 7.1.0-commandfiles-2-cb52137e732e7de23aae2ebaea799bcb    
-
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration()    
-
Find command files for phase 3 (max=)   
-
Returned from hook drush_provision_drupal_provision_backup_validate 
-
Calling hook drush_db_pre_provision_backup  
-
fopen(/production/my_aegir_user/platforms/template-uni-to/sites/www.mydomain.com/database.sql): failed to open stream: Permission denied mysql.php:227  
-
Could not write database backup file mysqldump  
-
filesize(): stat failed for /production/my_aegir_user/platforms/template-uni-to/sites/www.mydomain.com/database.sql mysql.php:263   
-
Undefined variable: err mysql.php:265   
-
Could not generate database backup from mysqldump. (error: )    
-
Returned from hook drush_db_pre_provision_backup    
-
Deleted mysql dump from sites directory 
-
Changes made in drush_db_pre_provision_backup have been rolled back.    
-
Command dispatch complete   
-
Returned from hook drush_hosting_task   
-
Invoking hosting_backup_task_rollback hooks.    
-
Changes made in drush_hosting_task have been rolled back.   
-
Command dispatch complete   
-
Updated task status to "Failed"

****my aegir root is not /var/aegir, but it is at /production/my_aegir_user
```

Answer (score 1):

The main error seems to be:

> fopen(/production/my_aegir_user/platforms/template-uni-to/sites/www.mydomain.com/database.sql):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied mysql.php:227

However, there may be other causes. The best way to find it would be to run the task in debug mode.

For example, as the 'aegir' user:

```
drush @example.org provision-backup --debug
```

PS: I stumbled on this question because I ran into a similar issue. You may have better chances at getting responses on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ (and tag your question with 'aegir').

Comment: hi bgm, thanks for  your answer, i'll verify and a'll make you know.

Comment: They've been closing Aegir issues on that site because they're not Drupal-specific (strangely).  So I think this is the better site for the moment.